# Yii2-How to hide a value from a dropdown list in javascript

Tags: javascript, yii2, hide

I have a dropdown list in which there are some static values.

```
    <?= $form->field($model, 'source')->dropDownList([''=>'Please Select','Farhan' => 'Farhan', 'Usman' => 'Usman','Waseem'=>'Waseem','Habib'=>'Habib', 'HESCO' => 'HESCO']) ?>
```

Corresponding HTML is

```
<select id="refnumbers-source" class="form-control" 
name="RefNumbers[source]" aria-required="true">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="Farhan">Farhan</option>
<option value="Usman">Usman</option>
<option value="Waseem">Waseem</option>
<option value="Habib">Habib</option>
<option value="HESCO">HESCO</option>
</select>
```

Now based on a user role in javascript I want to hide an option/value from the dropdown. I am able to get a user role but now I want to hide a value.

```
<?php
$script = <<< JS


 $(document).ready(function () {  

     if($user_role.val() === 1)

      //here I want to hide the value 'HESCO' from dropdownlist
     }); 
JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

How can I achieve this?

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$script = <<< JS
$(document).ready(function () {  
    if($user_role.val() === 1) {
        $("#refnumbers-source option[value='HESCO']").remove();
    }
}); 
JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```